How do I deploy Crowdsec on Kubernetes?
I tried using the official page https://docs.crowdsec.net/u/getting_started/installation/kubernetes
and had no luck. None of the resultant pods ran successfully nor could I get logs on any of them. I'm using Rancher v1.29.4+rke2r1.
There's a link on docs.crowdsec.net to this page: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/crowdsec/crowdsec#values
These two pages (docs.crowdsec.net and artifacthub.io) contain vastly different "basic" configurations, which is confusing. For instance, one page wants me to use Traefik while the other doesn't.
On the artifact.io page, one block of code in the same yaml file has password: ${DB_PASSWORD} while another block has dbPassword: <externalDbPassword>. Why might this be? Is there a technical reason for this divergence or is this more the result of two people making edits to the same web page over time without reading the original page? Perhaps this page was auto-generated or updated by a script.
In any case, I'm seeking advice regarding which page to use. I'm obviously not a Kubernetes expert so I'm having trouble deciding.
Thanks.
Adding my deployment yaml below. None of the resultant pods start.
config:
  config.yaml.local: |
    db_config:
      type:     postgresql
      user:     crowdsec
      password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      db_name:  crowdsec
      host:     192.168.10.132
      port:     5432
      sslmode:  require

agent:
  acquisition:
    - namespace: "crowdsec"       # Specify the namespace for the pods you want to monitor
      podName: "crowdsec-wutwut"      # Specify the pod name or pattern
      program: "/var/log/pods/*.log"  # Specify the log file path or a pattern to match
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "100m"  # Lower the CPU request
      memory: "128Mi"  # Lower memory if needed
    limits:
      cpu: "500m"  # Set a reasonable CPU limit
      memory: "256Mi"
  replicaCount: 1

lapi:
  # 2 or more replicas for HA
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "100m"  # Lower CPU request for LAPI
      memory: "128Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "500m"
      memory: "256Mi"
  replicas: 2
  # You can specify your own CS_LAPI_SECRET, or let the chart generate one. Length must be >= 64
  secrets:
    csLapiSecret: <t0iL3tj_sKw1dB@iT>
  # Specify your external DB password here
  extraSecrets:
    dbPassword: <F6-pxY8[l\_%*4d>
  persistentVolume:
    # When replicas for LAPI is greater than 1, two options, persistent volumes must be disabled, or in ReadWriteMany mode
    config:
      enabled: false
    # data volume is not required, since SQLite isn't used
    data:
      enabled: false
  # DB Password passed through environment variable
  env:
    - name: DB_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: crowdsec-lapi-secrets
          key: dbPassword

When I run,
kubectl -n crowdsec logs crowdsec-lapi-5cc7bf9b5-zjtwv

the error is:
Generate local agent credentials
level=fatal msg="failed to connect to database: failed creating schema resources: querying server version failed to connect to `host=192.168.10.132 user=crowdsec database=crowdsec`: failed SASL auth (FATAL: password authentication failed for user \"crowdsec\" (SQLSTATE 28P01))"

I can't tell if the pod is trying to create a database or what. The crowdsec database already exists and those aren't my actual passwords or secrets.

I just tried using the artifact recipe and saw these errors. I have no idea where in the yaml these are supposed to go.
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the following chart(s):
crowdsec:

agent.acquisition.0.namespace: String length must be greater than or equal to 1
agent.acquisition.0.podName: String length must be greater than or equal to 1
agent.acquisition.0.program: String length must be greater than or equal to 1

